# Как заменить начальные названия функций импортируя свою библиотеку python

Tags: python, python-3.x, библиотеки

Как изменить названия начальных функций импортируя свою библиотеку?
Для примера возьмем самый простой код.

```
print("Hello, world!")
```

А теперь представим, что я реализовал эту идею.

```
import my_lib
# Заменяет функцию print на echo

echo("Hello, world!")
# Старая команда print больше не работает
```

Но. Если убрать импорт этой библиотеки, то функция echo пропадет и заменятся print.

Comment: День добрый! Не могу понять зачем.. но возможно вам нужно ‘from my_lib import echo as print’ тогда встроенная функция print будет переопределена функцией echo из вашей библиотеки. И переименовывать ничего не нужно...

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: вы можете закрыть свой вопрос, пометив мой ответ как решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Оформлю свой комментарий как ответ:*

Можно переопределить встроенную функцию с помощью следующей конструкции импорта

```
from my_lib import echo as print

print("Hello, world!") # работает ваша функция echo
```